# Does anyone ever use Dynamic Transport Mode in Pro Tools?

Tags: pro-tools, dynamic

If you have never heard of this option and you use Pro Tools, please answer with that information because it answers my question.

Why is it useful?

What application does anyone use it for?

I read about it in the manual and I couldn't for the life of me figure out why anyone would ever use that feature.

Comment: needs to be off if you want to use pre and post roll properly for sure!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Ryan

I found DT very useful if you want for example listen to a song or ambience file very fast without the necessity of hit the space bar every time you change your cursor, but for this you need to activate Dynamic transport and then you need to activate "Link Time Line and Edit Selection" to work.

After that you just need to do 1 click with your mouse in the part of the audio region where you want to listen.

Comment: My god. That's genius. Thank you. Finally I have a use for it!!!

Comment: fwiw, as long as "Link Time Line and Edit Selection" is enabled, you can achieve this without having to be in Dynamic Transport mode - just click in the main ruler during playback.
That said, it is nice to be able to click actually within the tracks using Michel's Dynamic Transport option.

Answer (score 7):

When working with SFX for games, DT is a MUST. For example: I need to create an ambience loop 30 seconds long and I need to make the loop seamless. In this case I need to pay special attention to the transision from the end of the region to start the of the same region when playing in loop mode. I don't want to listen to the whole 30 seconds over and over, so I mark my region (or multiple regions) and then I start playing from just before the ending (0:28) and listen to the transition.

I would die without Dynamic Transport. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I hadn't used this option before either, but after reading the manual it does sound like it could be useful. It lets you start playback from anywhere on the timeline without losing your timeline/edit selection. Could be useful for doing a quick A/B comparison of two points in a timeline, while retaining an edit selection..?

Comment: Thanks - yeah I can think of a myriad of ways now. Auditioning ambiences, ABing samples, different mixes, finding the correct selection to make a loop, creating audience loops, etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use some time, almost always with the "Link timeline and edit selection" activated.

One great feature of Dynamic Transport is that if you grab and drag the little blue triangle in the ruler, all the automation update while you scrubbing the triangle, both forward and backward. This is great because you can see what the automation is doing while following the picture. It is really useful with pan.